# Close form after pressing MessageBox button

Tags: c#, winforms

Into a menu of my main form I have a button who opens another form like :

```
private void OpenResetPasswordForm()
{
    var resetPasswordForm = new ResetPasswordForm()
    {
        EmpGuid = EBResources.EmpGuid
    };

    resetPasswordForm.Show();
}
```

Then in menu option:

```
private void menuItem4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.OpenResetPasswordForm();
}
```

Once I'm into form I do an action who fires `MessageBox` like this:

```
 MessageBox.Show("Your password has been successfully changed ", "System Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
```

I want to know how can I close `OpenResetPasswordForm` if I click `MessageBoxButtons.OK` of `MessageBox`, is that possible? Regards

Note: I don't want to exit of application I just want to close current  form to be on my main form again

Comment: `MessageBox.Show` returns a `DialogResult` which you can use to check against `DialogResult.Ok` and call `Close()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show( ... );
if( result == DialogResult.OK ) {
    this.Close();
}
```